# how would i make this like of code have breaks between every item added to the list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function addItem() {
    var newItem = document.createElement("div");
    newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("box").value;
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
}
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
     width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}
input[type="button"] {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>2-DO 2DAY</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1><font size="7" color="1E00FF">2-DO 2DAY</font></h1>
<br/>
<p><font size="8" color="5572FF"><em>What To Do Today?</em></font></p>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="box" value="Click To Add Task"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Add Task" onclick="addItem();"/>
<br/>
<div id="list"></div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

basically all this does is when my button is pressed, it gets information from the box that you type into then adds it to a list. So yeah now i will type a bunch of random words because it says this is too much code and not enough words.

a bat named Jeff flew into the whale blubber to clean himself.

Comment: Can you add it as an snippet so we can run it from mobile phone?

Comment: Don't use the `<center>` or `<font>` tags. They don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<br>` to your function as follows:

```
function addItem() {
  var newItem = document.createElement("div"); 
  newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("box").value + '<br><br>'; 
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
}
```

I think to achieve what you want you actually need to attach two `<br>`s. Be also aware of correct use of break tag. In HTML break is `<br>` in XHTML is `<br />`.

Run the code snippet below to see it in action.

```js
function addItem() {
  var newItem = document.createElement("div");
  newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("box").value + '<br><br>';
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
}
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}
input[type="button"] {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1><font size="7" color="1E00FF">2-DO 2DAY</font></h1>
  <br/>
  <p><font size="8" color="5572FF"><em>What To Do Today?</em></font>
  </p>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="box" value="Click To Add Task" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Add Task" onclick="addItem();" />
  <br/>
  <div id="list"></div>
</center>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<br/>`?

Answer (score 1):

Adding line breaks to the end of the appended item is a BAD suggestion - yes it works but you are adding the line-breaks for the single purpose of spacing displayed content. Better to put the appended items in a semantically correct block level element such as a `<p>` (or apply css to an inline level element display:block) and then add margins to provide the spacing:

```
function addItem() {
  var newItem = document.createElement("p"); 
  newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("box").value; 
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
}

//css
#list p{margin:15px 0}
```

also - just for correctness -you are appending an item to a div with an id of "list" - but this is not a list. Would suggest either changing the name to reduce confusion about a div being a "list" or forget about creating elements that are appended into the div - and just create an actual list and all you have to do is append `<li>`'s to that list.

```
function addItem() {
  var newItem = document.createElement("li"); 
  newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("box").value; 
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
}

//html
 <ul id='list'></ul>

//css
#list li{display:block; margin:15px 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```js
function addItem() {
    var newItem = document.createElement("div");
    newItem.innerHTML = document.getElementById("box").value;
    newItem.classList.add('item');
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem);
}
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
     width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}
input[type="button"] {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}
.item::after {
    content: "\A\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>2-DO 2DAY</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1><font size="7" color="1E00FF">2-DO 2DAY</font></h1>
<br/>
<p><font size="8" color="5572FF"><em>What To Do Today?</em></font></p>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="box" value="Click To Add Task"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Add Task" onclick="addItem();"/>
<br/>
<div id="list"></div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

So all you need is to add a class `item` to the element and add an pseudo class to item with the `content` of a line break.